# htaccess redirection issue for www and https

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have domain - example.com. I am using Laravel 5.

I want always to redirect to https://www.example.com/beta

Right now, my htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /beta/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Right now, for example.com/beta - it redirects to https://example.com/beta

but when we go to www.example.com/beta - it redirects to http://www.example.com/https://www.www.example.com/beta

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /beta/

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to clear browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Your 2nd rule is adding `https` and `www` at the same time when request might already have `www`

Comment: @anubhava Dear can you answer my question if you have a time please ? [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435512/request-404-page-not-found-ajax)